SDL2 Events how to avoid monolithic control statement?
I'm using SDL2 in my game engine and I'm trying to figure out how I can prevent having a monolithic control statement like this:
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
                case SDLK_w:
               // Move player forward
                // if debug mode move camera forward
                // if in menu navigate the ui
            }
            break;
        case SDL_QUIT:
            running = false;
            break;

    }
}

For the sake of readability and length I kept it short, but basically having a case for every key I might want to use say ~10 and each might do multiple different things depending on the state of the game plus the plethora of other events I feel like it'll spiral out of control and become a big blob of ugly/messy code.
Looking for any suggestions on what I could do to approach this problem or if there's any typical solutions.

You already figured out a great way to do this: by invoking your own events based on the SDL events, and handling your own events elsewhere: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/210586/what-do-you-do-with-sdl2-events. If you're looking for something more maintainable in the long term (e.g. to support rebinding keys), you could also consider the Command Pattern: https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/command.html

See also https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/190070/how-do-i-implement-an-input-wrapper-like-unitys-in-sdl2  https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/89755/how-to-handle-multiple-events-in-sdl2-and-c

@Kevin oh my bad I didn't even realize I was logged into the wrong account. To be honest I don't actually know why I have two accounts with the same name haha.

Obligatory reminder that keycodes (event.key.keysym.sym and SDLK_w) will do the wrong thing on non-QWERTY keyboards, prefer event.key.keysym.scancode and SDL_SCANCODE_W.

@Konjointed If you accidentally created two accounts, you can go here to merge them.

@Konjointed Ignoring the multiple accounts, is there a reason why you don't want to use the event-driven setup you already came up with? Are any of the other questions/resources I linked to helpful?

@Kevin I was going to mention that the two links you shared in your second comment (specifically the second link) were really helpful, but I wasn't sure if that would be an appropriate comment for stacks standards. Anyway, yes they were helpful thank you! it cleared some of my confusion of events and a way to avoid the problem I was having.
